# "Свобода слова" — это фразеологизм?

Tags: фразеология, семантика, словосочетания

Написал в ЕГЭ в 24-м задании фразеологизм "свобода слова". Верно ли, что это именно фразеологизм?

Comment: Устойчивое словосочетание, термин из области социологии и политики. Есть статья о свободе слова в Конституции РФ.

Answer (score 3):

Фразеологизм — это устойчивое словосочетание, оборот речи, выражение, значение которого не складывается из значений составляющих его слов; идиома.

Заглянем в толковый словарь:
[свобода](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)
**6.** *чего и с инф.* Возможность действовать в какой-либо области без ограничений, запретов, беспрепятственно. *Свобода торговли. Свобода передвижения. Свобода печати. Свобода собраний. Свобода творчества. Свобода морей* (право осуществления государством морского судоходства и морских промыслов в открытом море). ***Свобода слова** и мысли* (право иметь и выражать свои взгляды). *Свобода мыслей, рассудка, духа* (независимость, самостоятельность мыслей, духа).

Словосочетание "свобода слова" используется давно, неразложимо, является одним членом предложения, имеет фиксированный лексический состав (с синонимами — *свобода логоса* или *независимость слова* — сочетание имеет совершенно другой смысл).

Имеется оно и во фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка:
[свобода слова](https://phraseology.academic.ru/11271/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) — право граждан свободно, беспрепятственно выражать свои мысли, убеждения в устной и письменной форме. *Сама Екатерина придавала очень большую цену тому, что свобода слова не стесняется ею* (Добролюбов. Русская сатира в век Екатерины).

Так что думаю я, что решение ваше является правильным.

[Что такое фразеологизмы](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/chto-takoe-frazeologizmy.html)

Comment: Скорее клише это.